# Return object instead of URL in django-oscar API response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-oscar

I am working on oscar based Ecom platform and in the `orderList` API, I want the object Instead of URL. I am new to Django and oscar. How can I do that? Please help me.

```
class OrderList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Order.objects.all()

        data=[]
        for q in list(qs):
            print(q)
        return qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

and it's serializer is :

```
class OrderSerializer(OscarHyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """
    The order serializer tries to have the same kind of structure as the
    basket. That way the same kind of logic can be used to display the order
    as the basket in the checkout process.
    """
    owner = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='user-detail', read_only=True, source='user')
    lines = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='order-lines-list')
    shipping_address = InlineShippingAddressSerializer(
        many=False, required=False)
    billing_address = InlineBillingAddressSerializer(
        many=False, required=False)

    payment_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    offer_discounts = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    voucher_discounts = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_offer_discounts(self, obj):
        qs = obj.basket_discounts.filter(offer_id__isnull=False)
        return OrderOfferDiscountSerializer(qs, many=True).data

    def get_voucher_discounts(self, obj):
        qs = obj.basket_discounts.filter(voucher_id__isnull=False)
        return OrderVoucherOfferSerializer(qs, many=True).data

    def get_payment_url(self, obj):
        try:
            return reverse('api-payment', args=(obj.pk,))
        except NoReverseMatch:
            msg = "You need to implement a view named 'api-payment' " \
                "which redirects to the payment provider and sets up the " \
                "callbacks."
            warnings.warn(msg)
            return msg

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = overridable('OSCARAPI_ORDER_FIELD', default=(
            'number', 'basket', 'url', 'lines',
            'owner', 'billing_address', 'currency', 'total_incl_tax',
            'total_excl_tax', 'shipping_incl_tax', 'shipping_excl_tax',
            'shipping_address', 'shipping_method', 'shipping_code', 'status',
            'guest_email', 'date_placed', 'payment_url', 'offer_discounts',
            'voucher_discounts')
        )
```

I need an object in the serializer but it's giving me a url instead. I tried to change the serializer but did not find a working solution.

Comment: Which particular field you want an object instead of URL? For example, you can change `owner` to an object instead of a URL, by doing something like `owner = UserSerializer()`.